# How can I use Genetic Algorithms to solve non-linear optimization problems in Python?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to apply the concept of Genetic Algorithm to solve a non-linear optimization problem in Python and compare the results with other methods. I am trying to solve min (x1.x2^2 + x1+x2) to get the optimal solution using GA. I have solved the problem using scipy and gekko , but i need to use GA for comparison and learning purposes.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JMetalPy](https://github.com/jMetal/jMetalPy), a Python implementation for the JMetal Meta-heuristic search library.

You need to define and implement how to encode your solutions and implement a fitness function.

Comment: Dear Fakher, thank you for your reply. My aim is to minimize the non-linear function: x1x2^2 + x2 +x1 ; I have solved this used scipy and gekko. However, I want to make sure if I can use GA to solve the same problem.

Comment: well, for that encode your solution as the pair of reals (x1, x2) and set the fitness function to -x1x2^2 + xx2 + x1. Also, if this was helpful please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: correction: the fitness function should be: - x1x2^2 -x2 - x1

Comment: Dear Fakher, I have one more question. How should I add the constraints to the problem? Suppose for instance x1+x2 <2 for instance.

Comment: ofcourse you should, and you do that when you are defining your solution space (set of feasible solutions). --please accept the answer if this was helpful(it's the tick under the upvote)